# Hashes array elements copy

Tags: arrays, perl, copy, element

My array of hashes:

```
@cur = [
          {
            'A' => '9872',
            'B' => '1111'
          },
          {
            'A' => '9871',
            'B' => '1111'
          }
        ];
```

Expected result:

```
@curnew = ('9872', '9871');
```

Any simple way to get only the values of the first hash element from
this and assign it to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your array have to be defined as

```
my @cur = (
    {
        'A' => '9872',
        'B' => '1111'
    },
    {
        'A' => '9871',
        'B' => '1111'
    }
);
```

Note the parenthesis

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @cur = (
    {
        'A' => '9872',
        'B' => '1111'
    },
    {
        'A' => '9871',
        'B' => '1111'
    }
);
my @new;
foreach(@cur){
    push @new, $_->{A};
}
dump @new;
```

Answer (score 8):

Mind that hashes are unordered, so I take the word *first* to mean *lexicographically first*.

```
map {                               # iterate over the list of hashrefs
    $_->{                           # access the value of the hashref
        (sort keys $_)[0]           # … whose key is the first one when sorted
    }
}
@{                                  # deref the arrayref into a list of hashrefs
    $cur[0]                         # first/only arrayref (???)
}
```

The expression returns `qw(9872 9871)`.

Assigning an arrayref to an array as in `@cur = […]` is probably a mistake, but I took it at face value.

---

Bonus [perl5i](http://p3rl.org/perl5i) solution:

```
use perl5i::2;
$cur[0]->map(sub {
    $_->{ $_->keys->sort->at(0) } 
})->flatten;
```

The expression returns the same values as above. This code is a bit longer, but IMO more readable because the flow of execution goes strictly from top to bottom, from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @hashes = map (@{$_}, map ($_, $cur[0]));
my @result = map ($_->{'A'} , @hashes);    
print Dumper \@result;
```